# Why doesn't my regex code get this part of the string?

Tags: android, json, regex, google-places-api

I'm making an app that shows the user the nearest gyms.  After I put in a request to the Google Places Api, it returns me some json.  I get the latitude from that json using regex.  However, I cannot get the longitude.  My code is below.  Can someone help please?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                String latitude = "\"lat\":";
                String longitude = "lng\":";
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(latitude +"(.*?),");
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(longitude + "(.*?)"+ ",");

                JSONObject jsonPart = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);



                String latLong = jsonPart.getString("geometry");
               Matcher m = p.matcher(jsonPart.getString("geometry"));
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(jsonPart.getString("geometry"));
               while( matcher.find()) {
                   Log.i("longitude", matcher.group(1));

               }
                while (m.find()){

                    Log.i("latitude", m.group(1));
                }






            }
```

This is the line I need to get the latitude and longitude from.  I can get the latitude, but longitude doesn't work.

```
gymlocation: {"location":{"lat":40.4434584,"lng":-79.964227}}
```

Comment: Compile your Pattern outside the for loop. The point is to get them compiled easily and then reuse that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String longitude = "\"lng\":";
```

You are missing `\"`

Alternatively, isn't this better?

[Geting json response from Google places API in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566585/geting-json-response-from-google-places-api-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use regex, your second expression `"lng"(.*?),` isn't finding anything because of the `?` lazy operator. It will try to match at least characters as possible , and as the string you're searching on has no `,` but your expression tries to match one at the end, it will just not match anything.